# ObservableCollection<MyCustomClass>.Contains(MyCustomObject.SomeProperty)

Tags: c#

How can I extend (or overload) Contains method with some custom property in a collection ?

I want that delegate to compare the object with just a property of it and returns true if there is an object with the same value of a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return myCollection.Any(myCustomObject => myCustomObject.SomeProperty.Equals(valueToFind));
```

Comment: oops easier than I thought, Thanks